# What does the instruction LODS DWORD PTR DS:[ESI]?

Tags: assembly

i have the following assembly instruction(as you can also see in the title):

```
 LODS DWORD PTR DS:[ESI]
```

On one website i have found out that:

```
 The lods instruction is unique among the string instructions. 
 You will never use a repeat prefix with this instruction. 
 The lods instruction copies the byte or word pointed at by ds:si 
 into the al, ax, or eax register, after which it increments or 
 decrements the si register by one, two, or four.
```

But I did not the understand the point: how can i be sure in which of the registers al, ax or eax the  byte or word is copied.

Can someone explain it to me in a more

Comment: Also, the reason that you don't use a rep prefix is that you need to inspect the loaded value somehow before repeating.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The size of the operation determines which register is targeted and how far the ESI register is advanced. For `LODS DWORD`, a double-word (32-bit) datum is loaded, which means the 32-bit EAX register. `LODS WORD` would be 16-bit into the 16-bit AX register, and `LODS BYTE` would be the 8-bit AL.

Comment: Frequently it's abbreviated as "lodsb", "lodsw", and "lodsd".

Comment: ahaaaa...ok. So the register choice depends on the "DWORD", "WORD" or "BYTE" , right?. Means that as you wrote "DWORD" ,then take the value in [ESI] into the EAX register, and so on...     ok, thank you